# Ubuntu apt mirror repository with debian-installer

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-14.04, repository, apt-mirror

I am trying to make a mirror of the ubuntu 14.04 repository that includes all the files necessary to be able to be used as a source repository during Ubuntu 14.04 server installation.

I had my apt-mirror mirror.list file containing:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main multiverse restricted universe
```

When installing ubuntu server it crashes because its missing debian-installer. So I tried adding these to mirror.list:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main/debian-installer multiverse/debian-installer restricted/debian-installer universe/debian-installer
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main/debian-installer multiverse/debian-installer restricted/debian-installer universe/debian-installer
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main/debian-installer multiverse/debian-installer restricted/debian-installer universe/debian-installer
```

Even after this the Ubuntu 14.04 server install CD is still failing... a look at the log and it is requesting items from pool that are not in any of the package lists above... so there is yet another package list I am missing? Worse is that I have no way of knowing which one it is because all of the package list downloads from the install CD are successful! So it seems to be requesting a package in a list it hasn't even downloaded (built into the ISO?).